# Proper response to SMTP HELO

Tags: email, smtp, network-protocols

The following is the beginning of an SMTP transaction example shown in the
textbook *Computer Networking (6th international edition)*:

```
S: 220 hamburger.edu
C: HELO crepes.fr
S: 250 Hello crepes.fr, pleased to meet you
```

The `S:` prefix indicates that it is a line sent by the server, `C:` that it is
a line sent by the client. The Wikipedia page [SMTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol#SMTP_transport_example) has an SMTP
example that has a similar response to `HELO`.

Is the server's response to `HELO` spec compliant? [RFC 5321](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321#page-33)
specifies the server's response to `HELO`/`EHLO` thus:

```
ehlo-ok-rsp    = ( "250" SP Domain [ SP ehlo-greet ] CRLF )
                    / ( "250-" Domain [ SP ehlo-greet ] CRLF
                    *( "250-" ehlo-line CRLF )
                    "250" SP ehlo-line CRLF )
```

As I understand the spec, the server's response in the above example should be

```
250 hamburger.edu
```

That is, it should respond with `250` followed by its own hostname, not the
client's hostname, and certainly not the arbitrary greeting message shown
in the example.

What is the proper response to `HELO`?
Is the *Computer Networking* example incorrect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The short answer**

The example is not valid due to the stray `Hello` just after the `250`. But.. that probably doesn't matter.

**The long(er) answer**

First let's look at the syntax for the client's "HELO":

> "HELO" SP Domain CRLF

The client sends `HELO` followed by a space, followed by his domain name, followed by a CRLF. How do I know that it's the clients domain? Well:

> The argument clause contains the fully-qualified domain name of the
>   SMTP client, if one is available

Now the response:

> ehlo-ok-rsp    = ( "250" SP Domain [ SP ehlo-greet ] CRLF )
>                       / ( "250-" Domain [ SP ehlo-greet ] CRLF
>                       *( "250-" ehlo-line CRLF )
>                       "250" SP ehlo-line CRLF )

There are two options here:

1. `"250" SP Domain [ SP ehlo-greet ] CRLF`
2. `( "250-" Domain [ SP ehlo-greet ] ...`

**Both of them don't fit** since the domain name is expected instead of the `Hello` we see.

The following `ehelo-greet` part is fine though. It is explained on the next page of the RFC:

> ehlo-greet     = 1*(%d0-9 / %d11-12 / %d14-127)
>                       ; string of any characters other than CR or LF

So it can be any string that doesn't contain `\r` or `\n`. The string `, pleased to meet you` clearly falls into that category.

**Why it doesn't matter**

Having said all of that, note that the fact that the example is invalid, doesn't mean that it doesn't happen in practice or that a server that would send such an example wouldn't work properly. There's a difference between theory and practice. For instance, if we look at Java's official [JavaMail](https://java.net/projects/javamail/sources/mercurial/content/mail/src/main/java/com/sun/mail/smtp/SMTPTransport.java), in `SMTPTransport.java`, on lines 1662-1665 we find the following code:

```
if (first) {    // skip first line which is the greeting
    first = false;
    continue;
}
```

This is from a method named `ehlo(String domain)` which handles sending and receiving the `HELO` command. JavaMail skips the entire greeting line, and I suspect that other client could be doing the same.

Comment: It does appear that it might be correct to reply to HELO with the client's "Domain", but Postfix and Exim both reply with their own domain. I agree that it is permissible to send include an arbitrary message in the rely to HELO, but surely the example in my question, "250 Hello crepes.fr, pleased to meet you" is wrong. Seems that it should be "250 crepes.fr Hello, pleased to meet you".

Comment: It's true that the RFC doesn't explicitly specify which domain name to return, but to me it seems that the authors meant the client's domain name. About the response in the example - you're right, I missed the stray Hello right after the 250. I'll update the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

RFC 821 didn't actually specify what the response to HELO is, but all the examples used the recipient's domain as the body of the message. Later RFCs have defined extended hello (EHLO) which actually has a defined format to the response. But given the lack of clarity in the original standard, practically speaking anything between the `250`  and the CR is kosher when the client is so careless as to send HELO instead of EHLO.